# Can't get toupper to work

Tags: r, toupper

I want to transform the contents of a factor column in a dataframe from lowercase to upper case. The function toupper(dataframe$columnname) prints the contents in uppercase, but nothing actually seems to happen to the contents. When I check using levels(dataframe$columnname) or just visually inspecting the dataframe, the contents are still in lowercase. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: you are not updating your vector by replacing them with `toupper` output. Maybe, `dataframe$columnname <- toupper(dataframe$columnname)` will work

Answer (score 1):

To change your data.taframe's content you must alter the columns values

```
dataframe$columnname <- toupper(dataframe$columnname)
```

Although, if you want to play with characters, do it like

```
dataframe$columnname <- toupper(as.character(dataframe$columnname))
```